# VueJS - updating URL with dynamic data

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a single page VueJS app with a number of data variables I want to encode into the URL.

As an example if my route configuration is (I'm not sure if the syntax is correct):

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/:foo/:bar/:oof/:rab',
        component: App
    }
```

And the Component is:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function() {
    return {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2,
      oof: 3,
      rab: 4
    }
  }
}
```

Then the URL would be `http://www.example.com/#/1/2/3/4`

And if `foo` is changed to 9999 the URL would automatically update: `http://www.example.com/#/9999/2/3/4`

It would also respond to the user changing the URL, or opening the app with a different URL by loading the URL values into the data.

I thought this would be relatively straightforward but after a Google I'm utterly confused by the correct way of going about this.

Any help/ examples/ solutions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever you use to change the values would need to trigger a route *push*. For example

```js
methods: {
  changeFoo (newFoo) {
    // you can set foo but it probably won't matter because you're navigating away
    this.foo = newFoo
    this.$router.push(`/${newFoo}/${this.bar}/${this.oof}/${this.rab}`)
  }
```

See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

---

It might be easier if you [name your route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html), eg

```js
routes: [{
  name: 'home',
  path: '/:foo/:bar/:oof/:rab',
  component: App
}]
```

then you could use something like

```js
this.$router.push({name: 'home', params: this.$data})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two things you're trying to achieve, but I'm not sure from your example which comes first in your ideal order of operations:

- Getting the values from your URL

  This can be achieved through `this.$route.params`, which will be an object containing the values you're looking for.
- Setting the URL based on your `foo`, `bar`, `oof`, `rab` variables

  You can use `this.$router.push()` to do this: [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)